# How to make UITabbar selectionIndicatorImage change when changing orientation - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, uitabbar

I uses an image for my tabbar selectionIndicatorImage. It works great in Portrait orientation. However, when I change to Landscape orientation, the selectionIndicatorImage is still using the image for Portrait. Therefore, the image's width doesn't fit my Tab bar size in Landscape.

[image: in Portrait]

[image: in Landscape]

How can I fixed this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the image from code depending on the orientation.
Like this:

```
// the function is called everytime bounds change
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let orientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
    if orientation == .Portrait {
        // I asssume you get images from Images.xcassets
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "image1")
    } else if orientation == .LandscapeLeft || orientation == .LandscapeRight {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "image2")
    }
}
```