# Tab Bar titles aren't staying in position when you change orientation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Heres the problem

**Portrait Mode :**

[image]

**Landscape Mode :**
[image]

So as you can see the offset doesnt scale properly, because i put 0,-17 when its potrait it shows normally but when you switch to landscape its the opposite like 0,17 instead. Im not sure how to fix..

Comment: Check this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191574/how-to-make-uitabbar-selectionindicatorimage-change-when-changing-orientation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Aleem Although thats for the image, i changed it to offset text right. But the text remains the same as in the picture (still bad) until its selected then it goes down to the wanted offset, Any solution?